# Get all Facebook friends that like a specific page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

is there an easy way to get all Facebook friends that like a specific Facebook page?

I know that there is this site here

https://www.facebook.com/browse/friended_fans_of/?page_id=245323855526590

Where you can type in the page_id and get all friends that like this. But is this also possible with the Graph API? Or would I need to go every friend of a user, using the correct permission and THEN check if the user likes a specific page? I couldn't find an API Endpoint in the API Reference of Facebook

Comment: /me/friends return all friends that are using the app and have granted user_friends. And then you can use user_likes to see if a user have liked a page.

Comment: Hi, thanks, but I'm not searching for friends for using my app, but rather for friends who are liking a specific page, like the one from Wayne Rooney or Beyonce etc.

Comment: The `friends_likes` permission has been deprecated, so there's no way to get this via the Graph API.

Comment: That is not possible

Comment: Hi, thank you guys. Then I'll flag this question and request a close